# BigQuery SPLIT() ignores empty values

Tags: google-bigquery

It appears that SPLIT() treats empty values as though they don't exist at all, which yields unexpected results.

For example:

```
SELECT
  NTH(3, SPLIT(values, ","))
FROM
  (SELECT "a,b,,d,e" as values)
```

returns "d", when I would expect it to return NULL. You can see how this would be problematic for several rows of comma-delimited text. One would expect the following query to return NULL and "c", but it doesn't:

```
SELECT
  NTH(3, SPLIT(values, ","))
FROM
  (SELECT "a,b,,d,e" as values),
  (SELECT "a,,c,d,e" as values)
```

Rather, it returns "d" and "d".

Is this behavior by design, can it be altered, or is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Typically when I have a CSV file and I want to import it into Google Big Query, I upload the csv file to google cloud storage, write a schema for it, and import it into google big query as a table.  The only way you'd need SPLIT() is if, say, you had JSON data that contained a field containing CSV data.  That being said, I'd agree this looks strange.

Comment: OK, good point -- I can't remember why I started down the path of loading the file in its raw form first, then using BQ to split. When I went back and loaded the CSV with a schema, it worked fine. Thanks! But yeah, SPLIT() still behaves differently than I'd expect, so I've altered the question just slightly to see if anyone has ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is By Design behavior, and it is not specific to SPLIT function, but to REPEATED fields in general. BigQuery REPEATED fields cannot store NULLs (same behavior as in protocol buffers), therefore nothing that SPLIT does can make NULLs appear inside REPEATED fields.

Answer (score 2):

As Mosha explains, obtaining NULLs from a SPLIT() operation is not possible. As an alternative, is getting empty spaces an option?

```
SELECT
  NTH(7, SPLIT(values, ","))
FROM
(SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(values, ',,', ', ,') values FROM
  (SELECT "a,b,,d,e,,g" as values),
  (SELECT "a,,c,d,e,f,g" as values),
  (SELECT "a,,c,d,e,f,," as values),
  (SELECT "a,,c,d,e,f," as values),
)

Row f0_  
1   g    
2   g    
3        
4   null
```

Comment: Yes, that's actually the approach I was using for a while, and works fine...ish. But of course having spaces where one expects to have NULLs is never optimal!

Comment: Coming soon: JavaScript UDFs :)